# Safari show only 3 columns instead 4

Tags: css, safari

I need to display 4 images in a row. It works in all browsers except Safari, where are displayed 3 images in the first row.

.............................................................................
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

```css
.page .services .services-img {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.page .services .services-img .wpb_column {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_inner vc_row-fluid services-img"><div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-3"><div class="vc_column-inner"><div class="wpb_wrapper">
 <div class="wpb_single_image wpb_content_element vc_align_left">
  
  <figure class="wpb_wrapper vc_figure">
   <div class="vc_single_image-wrapper   vc_box_border_grey"><img width="120" height="81" src="RGB-1.jpg" class="vc_single_image-img attachment-thumbnail" alt=""></div>
  </figure>
 </div>
</div></div></div><div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-3"><div class="vc_column-inner"><div class="wpb_wrapper">
 <div class="wpb_single_image wpb_content_element vc_align_left">
  
  <figure class="wpb_wrapper vc_figure">
   <div class="vc_single_image-wrapper   vc_box_border_grey"><img width="150" height="87" src="A1_01_08RED_TAG_3_L-1024x592-150x87.jpg" class="vc_single_image-img attachment-thumbnail" alt=""></div>
  </figure>
 </div>
</div></div></div><div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-3"><div class="vc_column-inner"><div class="wpb_wrapper">
 <div class="wpb_single_image wpb_content_element vc_align_left">
  
  <figure class="wpb_wrapper vc_figure">
   <div class="vc_single_image-wrapper   vc_box_border_grey"><img width="120" height="46" src="ntt_logopng.png" class="vc_single_image-img attachment-thumbnail" alt=""></div>
  </figure>
 </div>
</div></div></div><div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-3"><div class="vc_column-inner"><div class="wpb_wrapper">
 <div class="wpb_single_image wpb_content_element vc_align_left">
  
  <figure class="wpb_wrapper vc_figure">
   <div class="vc_single_image-wrapper   vc_box_border_grey"><img width="150" height="41" src="ald-automotive-logo-150x41.jpg" class="vc_single_image-img attachment-thumbnail" alt=""></div>
  </figure>
 </div>
</div></div></div><div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-3"><div class="vc_column-inner"><div class="wpb_wrapper">
 <div class="wpb_single_image wpb_content_element vc_align_left">
  
  <figure class="wpb_wrapper vc_figure">
   <div class="vc_single_image-wrapper   vc_box_border_grey"><img width="150" height="47" src="Union_CZ_LOGO_JPG-150x47.jpeg" class="vc_single_image-img attachment-thumbnail" alt=""></div>
  </figure>
 </div>
</div></div></div><div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-3"><div class="vc_column-inner"><div class="wpb_wrapper">
 <div class="wpb_single_image wpb_content_element vc_align_left">
  
  <figure class="wpb_wrapper vc_figure">
   <div class="vc_single_image-wrapper   vc_box_border_grey"><img width="120" height="80" src="Union-ZP-logo_120.jpg" class="vc_single_image-img attachment-thumbnail" alt=""></div>
  </figure>
 </div>
</div></div></div><div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-3"><div class="vc_column-inner"><div class="wpb_wrapper">
 <div class="wpb_single_image wpb_content_element vc_align_left">
  
  <figure class="wpb_wrapper vc_figure">
   <div class="vc_single_image-wrapper   vc_box_border_grey"><img width="150" height="84" src="aero-150x84.jpg" class="vc_single_image-img attachment-thumbnail" alt=""></div>
  </figure>
 </div>
</div></div></div><div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-3"><div class="vc_column-inner"><div class="wpb_wrapper">
 <div class="wpb_single_image wpb_content_element vc_align_left">
  
  <figure class="wpb_wrapper vc_figure">
   <div class="vc_single_image-wrapper   vc_box_border_grey"><img width="120" height="74" src="zbrojovka_120.png" class="vc_single_image-img attachment-thumbnail" alt=""></div>
  </figure>
 </div>
</div></div></div><div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-3"><div class="vc_column-inner"><div class="wpb_wrapper">
 <div class="wpb_single_image wpb_content_element vc_align_left">
  
  <figure class="wpb_wrapper vc_figure">
   <div class="vc_single_image-wrapper   vc_box_border_grey"><img width="120" height="22" src="Hydra-with-R_120.jpg" class="vc_single_image-img attachment-thumbnail" alt=""></div>
  </figure>
 </div>
</div></div></div><div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-3"><div class="vc_column-inner"><div class="wpb_wrapper">
 <div class="wpb_single_image wpb_content_element vc_align_left">
  
  <figure class="wpb_wrapper vc_figure">
   <div class="vc_single_image-wrapper   vc_box_border_grey"><img width="120" height="63" src="LINET_logo_120.jpg" class="vc_single_image-img attachment-thumbnail" alt=""></div>
  </figure>
 </div>
</div></div></div><div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-3"><div class="vc_column-inner"><div class="wpb_wrapper">
 <div class="wpb_single_image wpb_content_element vc_align_left">
  
  <figure class="wpb_wrapper vc_figure">
   <div class="vc_single_image-wrapper   vc_box_border_grey"><img width="150" height="79" src="economia-og-150x79.png" class="vc_single_image-img attachment-thumbnail" alt=""></div>
  </figure>
 </div>
</div></div></div></div>
```

Has anyone else experienced this issue, and know of a fix?

Comment: Hi, where is the HTML code?

Comment: It is created with page builder WP Bakery so it's not typical HTML code. I added snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best way to use the width with the flex-box.

Try to replace `width: 25%;` with `flex-basis: 25%;`.

I hope that helps you.

Comment: I am trying the same HTML and CSS code and it's work without any problems on safari, What is the version of safari do you have.

Comment: Can you give me all the styles, please?

Comment: I changed it on flex-basis: 24.9%; and it works. So i think solved.

Comment: Congratulation!